# Vertical Table, data fetched dynamically

Tags: php, sql, dynamic, html-table

I am trying to make a table, which has:

- The column names on the left side.
- The data vertically.
- Expanding horizontally instead of vertically on next sql row.

In short the exact opposite of a normal table.

Also the horizontally expanded data will have a header on top named, Solution X (X for the number of the actaul column, the picture makes everything clear).

I have added a picture which should make it clear enough what I try to achieve, with guidelines.!

Image:

[image]

The code which is doing this is:

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Solution 1</th>
    <th>Solution 2</th>
    <th>Solution 3</th>
  </tr>
  <?
 while($result = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
 { ?>
  <tr>
    <td>SHIPPINGLINE</td>
    <th><? echo $result["SHIPPINGLINE"]; ?></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>POL</td>
    <th><? echo $result["POL"]; ?></th>
  </tr>
  <?
 } 

 //This counts the number or results - and if there wasn't any it gives them a little     message explaining that 
 $anymatches=mysql_num_rows($data); 
 if ($anymatches == 0) 
 { 
 echo "Sorry, but we can not find an entry to match your query.<br><br>"; 
 } 

 //And we remind them what they searched for 
 echo "<b>Searched For:</b> " .$findone. " and " .$findtwo;
 } 
 ?>
    </table>
```

I am stuck, because as you see what keeps happening is that the next 'sql row' that is fetched, appears below the first all the time. What I want is that each next 'sql row' must come under the next 'solution number'.

I would appreciate it a lot if you can help me on this one. If you need more details, please feel free to ask :).

Comment: You may have a loop after each <tr>, so suppose you have three rows then you must have three loops.

Comment: If possible, please edit my code, I am not sure how I should loop it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$output = array();
$c=1;
while($result = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
{
  $output[$c]['shippingline'] = $result['shippingline'];
  $output[$c]['pol'] = $result['pol'];
      $c++;
}
?>
<table border="1">
<tr>
<th></th>
<?php
foreach ($output as $key => $html)
{
echo "<th>Solution ".$key."</th>";
}
?>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Shipping Line</td>
<?php
foreach ($output as $key => $html)
{
echo "<td>".$html['shippingline']."</td>";
}
?>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>POL</td>
<?php
foreach ($output as $key => $html)
{
echo "<td>".$html['pol']."</td>";
}
?>
</tr>   
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot there! Works perfectly, and is clean enough for me to understand and re-edit to add more fields/columns. You get the idea :).